# How to get just links of articles in list using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

Hey guess so I got as far as being able to add the `a` class to a list. The problem is I just want the href link to be added to the `links_with_text` list and not the entire a class. What am I doing wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import requests 

URL = "https://news.ycombinator.com"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id = 'hnmain')
articles = results.find_all(class_="title")
links_with_text = []
for article in articles:
    link = article.find('a', href=True)
    links_with_text.append(link)

    print('\n'.join(map(str, links_with_text)))
```

This prints exactly how I want the list to print but I just want the href from every a class not the entire a class. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't SHOUT.

Comment: sorry about that had caps on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all links from the `https://news.ycombinator.com`, you can use CSS selector `'a.storylink'`.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import requests

URL = "https://news.ycombinator.com"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

links_with_text = []
for a in soup.select('a.storylink'):        # <-- find all <a> with class="storylink"
    links_with_text.append(a['href'])       # <-- note the ['href']

print(*links_with_text, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2020/06/18/introducing-firefox-private-network-vpns-official-product-the-mozilla-vpn/
https://mxb.dev/blog/the-return-of-the-90s-web/
https://github.blog/2020-06-18-introducing-github-super-linter-one-linter-to-rule-them-all/
https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2018/11/why-536-was-worst-year-be-alive
https://www.strongtowns.org/journal/2020/6/16/do-the-math-small-projects
https://devblogs.nvidia.com/announcing-cuda-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2/
https://lwn.net/SubscriberLink/822568/61d29096a4012e06/
https://imil.net/blog/posts/2020/fakecracker-netbsd-as-a-function-based-microvm/
https://jepsen.io/consistency
https://tumblr.beesbuzz.biz/post/621010836277837824/advice-to-young-web-developers
https://archive.org/search.php?query=subject%3A%22The+Navy+Electricity+and+Electronics+Training+Series%22&sort=publicdate
https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2020/06/ff-sandbox-escape-cve-2020-12388.html?m=1
https://apnews.com/1da061ce00eb531291b143ace0eed1c9
https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/appleid/android-apple-music-account-payment-none.jpg
https://standpointmag.co.uk/issues/may-june-2020/the-healing-power-of-birdsong/
https://steveblank.com/2020/06/18/the-coming-chip-wars-of-the-21st-century/
https://www.videolan.org/security/sb-vlc3011.html
https://onesignal.com/careers/2023b71d-2f44-4934-a33c-647855816903
https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-53006790
https://github.com/efficient/HOPE
https://everytwoyears.org/
https://www.historytoday.com/archive/natural-histories/intelligence-earthworms
https://cr.yp.to/2005-590/powerpc-cwg.pdf
https://quantum.country/
http://www.crystallography.net/cod/
https://parkinsonsnewstoday.com/2020/06/17/tiny-magnetically-powered-implant-may-be-future-of-deep-brain-stimulation/
https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-3-0-0.html
https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.09624
https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2020/06/18/data-privacy-law-sherrod-brown/
https://blog.chromium.org/2020/06/improving-chromiums-browser.html
```